# Azure Key Vault with Logic app, but empty Event section

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

Why I'm not seeing newly created Logic app in the event section?

I've done everything like in this manual - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-logicapps.

And this login app doesn't firing when event is occurred.
[image]

Comment: You need to save the Logic app in order to view it over Event Subscriptions

Comment: @SwethaKandikonda-MT I've saved Logip app, app is also presend in Azure Logic App Service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reproducing from our end here is how we could able to add the event subscription manually. Navigate to your **Key vault >> Events >> +Event Subscription**

[image]

Create a new logic app and use the same flow as mentioned in the attached manual. Now navigate to **logic app >> properties >> Copy Access Endpoint**

[image]

Now use the same endpoint in adding the event subscription

[image]

**RESULT:**
Now you can check from your event subscriptions

[image]

[image]

---

**NOTE:** Make sure you are creating the logic app in the same location as the key vault and create the flow first before adding the access endpoint during event subscription creation.

Comment: thanks for this manual, but when I'm trying to create event subscription System Topic Name created succesfully, but after that throws an error:
"Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for https://...... Http POST request failed with response code Unknown"

Comment: @Kavrat Apart from the error can you see the logic app getting added to the event subscription?

Comment: no, in Event Grid System Topic says "No Event Subscriptions Found" below

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've registered Event Grid as a resource provider in the subscription.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-logicapps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).